# Unity2D Set Time Trial That Kills Player When Over

Tags: time, unity-game-engine, 2d, limit

I can't find any answers to this. What I want is to set a 5 min time limit that begins when the level begins and ends when level ends. I also want it to kill the player if it runs out. This is for Unity2D and I want the timer to be seen at top left or right of screen. So basically I need a time limit like that of Super Mario. In C# code please.

Comment: You need to [google unity timer](https://www.google.ge/search?q=unity+timer&oq=unity+timer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3237j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#q=unity+timer+c%23) , then you'd need to understand [lifecycle of Unity objects](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) , then you'd probably need to [Destroy your player](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) then try to understand [unity canvas](https://www.google.ge/search?q=unity+canvas&oq=unity+canvas&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l2j0l2j69i60.1563j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Break up your problem into easier tasks. You will need some type of timer, and you will want to know how to 'kill' the player.

To create a timer, you can take advantage of how Update runs once per frame. Unity also comes with a Time class. In Time, there is a variable deltaTime which keeps track of the time in seconds to complete the last frame. Some other things you might want to add on to your class that acts as a timer is when to start and stop the timer.

To output the value from a timer to the game, you might want to use Unity's UI system and canvas. You might create a text object that is part of a canvas and anchor that text object to the top left corner.

To 'kill' a player, you can have some method that runs once the timer reaches the time in question and run the kill logic you want.

Helpful links:
MonoBehavior Update: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html
Time: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time.html
UI: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class that keeps track of the timer and to check if the requirements to fail are still there.

In this case you can have a float for the timer, and a bool for the condition whenever you completed the level or not.

It the timer reaches zero, check if the bool is still false, if it is, then you call something like KillPlayer(). If you complete the level by hitting a trigger or anything that will know if the level should be considered finished, you set the bool to true.

So your final check could look like this:

```
public float levelTimer = 300f;
public bool levelComplete = false;

void Start()
{
     levelTimer = 300f;
     levelComplete = false;
}

void Update()
{
    levelTimer -= Time.deltaTime;     

    if(levelTimer <= 0 && !levelComplete)
    {
       KillPlayer();
       //Something like a Game Over screen maybe
    }
}
```

I hope this help you in the right direction.